# How can I deal with special characters/ html code in mySQL query?

Tags: mysql, special-characters

I am using some html code inside the mySQL query:

```
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT("<i class=\'fa fa-circle-o\' style=\'color:",
  CASE
     WHEN animals.color = "red" THEN "#62bbd1"
     WHEN animals.color = "blue" THEN "#e9a5a9"
     WHEN animals.color = "orange" THEN "#ca6073"
     WHEN animals.color = "yellow" THEN "#c5b454"
     ELSE "#b7b7b7"
     END,"\'></i> ",animals.name) 
  ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(animals.color,"red,blue,orange,yellow,black") ASC, animals.name ASC SEPARATOR " <br>") AS animals,
```

It is all working well.
But I have problems, when `animals.name` has special characters. 
For example:

```
James-Lauren
Eva 1:2
Margeret (coordinator)
```

This means I get a correct output until that word with special characters. Then the output stops.

Comment: I tried `mysql_real_escape_string(animals.name)` but I get an error message `Syntax error or access violation: 1305`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the expected output and what do you get?

Please note that the maximum returned length in bytes for GROUP_CONCAT is determined by the `group_concat_max_len` server system variable.

Comment: Should not have something to do with the output length. Because it is working well, when I remove the html code

Comment: The problem is the conflict between html code and special characters.

Comment: Is there a better way to escape the quotes of the html code?

Comment: For example if I have this values in the mySQL table: `Sara, Elliot, Laura, Vincent, Adele, James-Lauren, Eva 1:2, Margeret (coordinator)` then the output I get is `<i></i>Sara<br><i></i> Elliot<br><i></i> Laura<br> <i></i>Vincent<br><i></i>Adele<br>`

Comment: If I have this values in the mySQL table: `Sara, Elliot, Laura, Vincent, Adele, James, Eva, Margeret` then the output I get is `<i></i>Sara<br><i></i> Elliot<br><i></i> Laura<br> <i></i>Vincent<br><i></i>Adele<br><i></i>James<br><i></i>Eva<br><i></i>Margeret<br>`

Comment: Use the provided SQL Fiddle and put your data in and show the problem.

Comment: It is like you posted more or less in the fiddle. I don't know how to change it. But on my website there is a problem accuring. I do not know why

Comment: it is working when I change the class `fa fa-circle-o` into a one word class like `myclass`